# How to use the property of an object as a source in the admin-on-rest?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

my friends.
I want to add a field associated with another resource like here: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Tutorial.html#relationships

But my problem is that field with id of other resource contain in object:

```
{
"id": 1,
 ....,
 user: {
     id: "12313123"
 }
}
```

What can I do in this situation? I already understand that I can create my own "Filelds", but how can I create my own "ReferenceField"? I need that "source" property contain something like this:

```
       <ReferenceField label="User" source="user.id" reference="users">
            <TextField source="name" />
        </ReferenceField>
```

Comment: I don't understand. It looks like you have a user object with another user in it.. why? And where is the `name` attribute? Inside the nested `user: { id ... }` ?

Comment: no, the root object - it's, for example, "Post" object. Every post have author-user.  I mistaked, object "user" contain property "name" too. In Docs example "Post" object contain "userId" property directly, It's number there. But for me it is object with id property, so my source it's not "user", it's "user.id". But I don't know how to do it

Comment: Kind of curious if any of the suggestions I had worked. Any luck?

Comment: @jonahe It was very simple. It's really work like source="user.id", but when I  maked this question I just thought that it will be impossible, so it work like I thought it must work))) Thanks for help, my friend!

Comment: Haha, ok that's good to hear! :) For future questions, be sure to mention the fact that you haven't tried to run the code. (Or else most readers will assume the code you post is code that you have tried and that it did not work. And they will try to fix a problem that doesn't really exist.).

Comment: By the way: you can actually post an answer to your own question and accept it, so that future readers will see the solution. I recommend you do that. It's pretty easy: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very simple. It's really work like source="user.id", but when I maked this question I just thought that it will be impossible, so it work like I thought it must work)))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the `admin-on-rest` framework, but from the documentation it seems like you could possibly [create a custom TextField relatively simply](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component). Maybe you could do a similar thing for creating a custom ReferenceField.

```js
import get from 'lodash.get'; // for safe access of nested data

const PostUserField = ({record}) => {
   // "record" is the post object in this example
   return ( 
     <ReferenceField label="User" source={ get('user.id', record) } reference="users">
        <TextField source="name" />
     </ReferenceField>
   );
}
```

And then call it like

```
// inside your other component..
<PostUserField />
```

If that doesn't work, I would then try to see if you could overwrite the `record` prop in your custom component, so that the access is no longer nested. In this contex, `id` would then point to the same property that was previously `user.id`.

```js
const PostUserField = ({record}) => {
   // "record" is the post object in this example
   // Prepare the record for the reference field, by removing
   // the nesting
   const unnestedUser = record.user;
   return ( 
     <ReferenceField record={ unnestedUser } label="User" source="id" reference="users">
        <TextField source="name" />
     </ReferenceField>
   );
}
```

Actually, now that I look at the problem again.. are you sure you even need a `ReferenceField` to fetch the user by id (user.id)? Because your post already seem to have the User data. So then you could solve it with a custom TextField like:

```js
import get from 'lodash.get';
// "record" is still a Post object. But since the data is already on
// the Post object (in user.name) , we can print it directly
const PostUserName = ({record }) => <span>{get(record, 'user.name')}</span>;
```